# `read` command not working in a Makefile

Tags: shell, make, variable

I have a make script to perform 3 tasks:

1. Import a MySQL database
2. Move a configuration file
3. Configure the configuration file

For these tasks, the script requires 3 inputs:

1. MySQL Host
2. MySQL Username
3. MySQL Password

For some reason, whenever I `read` an input, it saves to the right variable, but the content is the variable name that I save it to without the first letter. I can't seem to find out why it does that.

Here's the `Makefile`:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

default:
        @echo "Welcome!";\
        echo -n "Please enter the MySQL host (default: localhost):";\
        read host;\
        host=${host:-localhost};\
        echo -n "Please enter the MySQL username:";\
        read username;\
        echo -n "Please enter the MySQL password:";\
        read -s password;\
        mv includes/config.php.example includes/config.php 2>/dev/null;true;\
        sed 's/"USER", ""/"USER", "$(username)"/g' includes/config.php > includes/config.php;\
        sed 's/"PASSWORD", ""/"PASSWORD", "$(password)"/g' includes/config.php > includes/conf$
        echo $username;\
        echo $password;\
        mysql -u "$username" -p"$password" codeday-team < ./codeday-team.sql;\
        echo "Configuration complete. For further configuration options, check the config file$
        exit 0;
```

The output is:

```
Welcome!
Please enter the MySQL host (default: localhost):
Please enter the MySQL username:<snip>    
Please enter the MySQL password:sername
assword
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'sername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Configuration complete. For further configuration options, check the config file includes/config.php
```

As you can see, it outputs `sername` and `assword`. For the life of me I can't fix this!

While the purpose of this post is to solve the `read` bug, I would appreciate any advice, bugs reports, or suggestions. I may award a bounty for them.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: `$` characters need to be escaped as `$$` in Makefile if you want them passed to the shell. I'd use a script here and avoid passing the password on the command line.

Comment: Note that some of the lines are truncated and with a trailing `$` in there as if they were copy-pasted from `nano`.

Comment: The echoing of the password was just for checking why it wasn't working. It won't be there until he official script. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mixing shell and `make` variables in there. Both `make` and the shell use `$` for their variables.

In Makefile, variables are `$(var)` or `$v` for single-letter variables, and `$var` or `${var}` in shells.

But if you write `$var` in a Makefile, `make` will understand it as `$(v)ar`. If you want to pass a literal `$` to the shell, you need to enter it as `$$`, as in `$$var` or `$${var}` so that it becomes `$var` or `${var}` for the shell.

Also, `make` runs `sh`, not `bash` to interpret that code (**Edit**, sorry missed your `SHELL := /bin/bash` above, note that many systems don't have `bash` in `/bin` if they have `bash` at all and `:=` is GNU specific), so you need to use `sh` syntax there. `echo -n`, `read -s` are `zsh`/`bash` syntax, not `sh` syntax.

Best here would be to add a `zsh`/`bash` script to do that (and add a build dependency on `bash`). Something like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
printf 'Welcome\nPlease enter the MySQL host (default: localhost): '
read host || exit
host=${host:-localhost}
printf "Please enter the MySQL username: "
read username || exit
printf "Please enter the MySQL password:"
IFS= read -rs password || exit
printf '\n'
mv includes/config.php.example includes/config.php 2>/dev/null
repl=${password//\\/\\\\}
repl=${repl//&/\\&}
repl=${repl//:/\\:}
{ rm includes/config.php && 
  sed 's/"USER", ""/"USER", "'"$username"'"/g
       s:"PASSWORD", "":"PASSWORD", "'"$repl"'"/g' > includes/config.php
} < includes/config.php || exit
mysql -u "$username" -p"$password" codeday-team < ./codeday-team.sql || exit

echo "Configuration complete. For further configuration options, check the config file"
```

It addresses a few more issues:

- you need `-r` when reading the password if you want to allow the user to use backslashes in their password.
- you need `IFS=` if you want to allow the user to have a password that starts or ends in blanks
- same would apply for the username, but here we're making the assumption that the user won't use anything silly for the username, and the blank stripping and backslash handling could be seen as a /feature/.
- your `;true` after `mv` doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't cancel the effect of the `errexit` option (for `make` implementations that call the shell with `-e`). You'd need `||true` instead. Here, we're not using `errexit` but doing the error handling ourselves with `|| exit` where needed.
- You need to escape backslash, `&` and the `s:pattern:repl:` separator (here `:`) or it won't work (and could have nasty side effects).
- You can't do `sed ... < file > file`, as `file` would be truncated before `sed` is even started. Some `sed` implementations support a `-i` or `-i ''` option for that. Alternatively you could use `perl -pi`. Here we're doing the equivalent of `perl -pi` manually (delete and recreate the input file after it has been open for reading) but without taking care of the file's metadata.

  Here, it would be better to use the *example* one as input and the final one as output.

It still doesn't address a few more issues:

- the new `config.php` is created with permissions derived from the current `umask` which is likely to be *world readable* and owned by the user running `make`. You may need to adapt the `umask` and/or change ownership if the `includes` dir is not otherwise restricted as that file contains sensitive information.
- if the password contains `"` characters, that will likely break (this time for `php`). You'd want to either forbid those (by returning an error) or add another layer of escaping for them in the right syntax for that `php` file. You're likely to have similar problems with backslash and you may want to exclude non-ascii or control characters as well.
- Passing the password on the command-line of `mysql` is generally a bad idea as that means it shows in the output of `ps -f`. It would be better to use:

  ```
   mysql --defaults-file=<(
     printf '[client]\nuser=%s\npassword="%s"\n' "$username" "$password") ...
  ```

  `printf` being built-in, it wouldn't show up in `ps` output.
- the `$host` variable is not used.
- prompting the user like that means that your script can not easily be automated. You could take the input from arguments or (better for the password) with environment variables instead.

Comment: I'm going to award this answer with a bounty. It's eligible in two days. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

you are using no features of Makefile, have you try writing those lines in a single shell ?

next in a Makefile you use

```
    echo $username;\
    echo $password;\
```

make will parse `$username` as `$u` (empty variable) + `sername` (string)

try replacing `$username` by `$$username` if you want to stay in Makefile.